# When can an adjective be only used in certain forms?

Tags: adjective, grammar-identification

Today I heard that the adjective "unterstützend" can only be used in attributive and not predicative.  Is this true?

Furthermore,  how can we know the form of usage of adjective is restricted generally speaking?

Comment: Is that true? `Sie hat eine unterstützende Funktion` vs `Ihre Funktion ist unterstützend.`

Comment: There are, however, adjectives that can only be used in either way. E.g., _OK_ and _super_ only work predicatively; I can't think of an opposite example, but I remember there are some.

Comment: I think false premise questions can be on topic. Some time many people have the same false premise and taking the specific case where false premise is shown and giving instruction on general method is helpful. @infinitezero

Comment: @phipsgabler: The adjective *»super«* can also be used adverbial *Du siehst super aus. Das schmeckt super. Lisa kann super tanzen.* and also attributive: *Georg ist ein super Koch. Ich hatte gestern eine super Idee.* It is just indeclinable and incomparable in standard German, but in colloquial speech I also have heard *ein superer Koch, eine supere Idee.*

Comment: A false premise is not a reason to close a question. False premises only show that there is a misunderstanding that should be corrected in an answer.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast the false premise was that "my friend told me". If my friend tells me "paper does not burn if you hold it in a candle" and I'm asking "why doesn't it burn?" and the answer is, "well your friend is wrong, paper does burn", then there's not really a question left to answer.

Comment: The premise (that not all adjectives can be used predicatively) is correct and a common topic of grammar books; see for instance the Duden grammar, 9th edition, paragraph 481.

Comment: @infinitezero: And that's why I lit the paper and proved that it burns: I gave examples in my answer that prove the assumption is false. This is how you deal with false assumptions.

Comment: @DavidVogt: It is correct, that there are some adjectives, that can only be used attributive (for example *»gaußsch«*: korrekt: *»Die gaußsche Glockenkurve verläuft gekrümmt.«* but wrong: *»Die gekrümmte Glockenkurve verläuft gaußsch.«* also wrong: *»Die gekrümmte Glockenkurve ist gaußsch.«*  But this was not the assumption. The assumption was, that "unterstützend" is one of these words, and this assumption is wrong.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast You are ignoring the title and second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I disagree. I upvoted your answer btw. My whole point is that it's not necessary to light the paper because it's obvious it burns. So yes, one can do that. But once one realises that the initial claim was wrong, the need for the question disappears. I think the question in general is an interesting one, but currently it's mixed and currently answers are addressing precisely the wrong premise. Ideally, the false premise would need to be removed, but that would invalidate some answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong.

1. The word *»unterstützend«* is a participle, not an adjective. (But participles can be used like adjectives, so this is only half wrong.)
2. The participle *»unterstützend«* can be used attributive, predicative and adverbial, like almost all participles and adjectives.

- attributive
  Describing a property of a noun (here: *Handlung*), both words are within the same nominal group.

  > Dank der **unterstützenden** Handlung von Dr. Gruber geht es dem Kind jetzt besser.
- predicative
  Also describing a property of a noun (here: *Handlung*), but the adjective/participle is not part of the nouns nominal group. It is outside and coupled to it via a copula (coupling verb like *sein, werden, bleiben*)

  > Vielen Dank, sehr geehrter Dr. Gruber. Ihre Handlung war **unterstützend,** hilfreich und selbstlos.
- adverbial
  Not describing a property of a noun but of a verb (here: *handelte,* a form of *handeln*).

  > Das Kind konnte gerettet werden. Dr. Gruber handelte **unterstützend,** hilfreich und selbstlos. Die Eltern des Kindes dankten ihm dafür.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the present participle in German is most often used as attributive, i.e. like an adjective. This is different from English, where the present participle is the main ingredient to form the present continuous tense (which is not possible in German). Other than in English and differing from the past participle, the present participle is not used to form a certain tense. That was probably the thing your helping friend wanted to point out.

You can, however, use the present participle in German to express ongoing actions, like in

> Der Mann geht singend durch das Haus

(two actions are happening in parallel; the man is both singing and walking, and the present participle is used like an adverb, so predicative use)

The same works with *unterstützend*:

> Die Feuerwehr löschte den Brand und die Nachbarn griffen unterstützend ein.

Again, used like an adverb, the neighbors were both supporting and stepping in - predicative use.

Answer (score 1):

Though some may disagree with my definitions here, an adjective can be used in four ways in German, as a noun modifier (inflected and before the noun) as a predicate (uninflected, after a copulative verb), as a verb modifier (in other words an adverb) or a modifier of another word, usually another modifier. (The last is also called an adverb in English, which is unfortunate because they are different uses and English has the quirky idea that both should have the same "-ly" suffix.) Most adjectives are only ever used in some of these ways, sometimes because those are the only ones that make sense and sometimes because that's just the way the word is used. English sometimes works the same way, though English does add suffixes to distinguish between adjectives and adverbs. For example you can say "There was a lone hunter in the woods," but you can't say "The hunter in the woods was lone." As for how you can tell, I'm pretty sure it's just something you have to memorize when you learn the word. German often has a lot more of this "supporting data" associated with a word than English, gender and plural for nouns, irregular conjugation for verbs, case for prepositions, etc. So one more thing to add to the pile.